# How to remove the first tick in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am drawing a graph using d3.

```
let y = scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
let y_axis = axisLeft(y);

g.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(transltion," + height + ")")
   .call(axisRight(y).ticks(tick))
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + yLeftTrasltion+ "," + yBotmrasltion + ")");
```

This is plotting 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50. Now, I want it to not display 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Option 1: `d3.selectAll(".tick").filter(function (d) { return d === 0;  }).remove();`

Comment: Option 2: `.call(axisRight(y).ticks(tick).tickFormat(function(d){if(d)return d}))`

Comment: Option 3: `d3.select(".tick").remove()`

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `0` and with that the first tick you have two options:

1. Call `.tickValues()` on the axis elements and pass it an array of values that you would like to display. So in your case without the `0` it would be `[10,20,30,40,50]`. That way you will no longer get a 0 rendered on the axis. Full example would look like this:

`axisRight(y).tickValues([10,20,30,40,50]);`

2. More manual option is to run a select and remove it manually. Let's say your axis has a class `.axis`. You could run a d3 select to remove first tick manually. Beware that option 1 is a lot nicer and cleaner though. The manual removal would look like this:

`d3.select('.axis .tick:first-child').remove()`

Comment: in my case, I am using  ' .call(axisRight(y).ticks(tick))' . here i have fixed the number of ticks that is 5. but the interval will be different like [10,20,30,40,50] or [100,200,300,400,500], it can be anything.

Comment: In that case it probably makes sense to use the option 2 i described above @rajeevtejapuriya

Comment: i am not using any class for the axis.

Comment: Doesn't really matter as long as you have some way of identifying the element that contains your axis. Otherwise add a class `.attr('class', 'axis')` which is probably best practice to have either way

Answer (score 0):

Use 'fill-opacity'.

```
.style('fill-opacity', d => d === 0 ? 0.0 : 1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would help
x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
.scale(xscale).tickSizeOuter([40]).tickSizeInner([0]);

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS:

```
.tick:first-of-type line{
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
}
```